# How can I run a PHP project deployed in Heroku locally on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, heroku

Operating system: Windows.

```
C:\Users\vigne>cd project
C:\Users\vigne\project>heroku local // Directory of cloned project from GitHub
```

I received this:

```
[WARN] No ENV file found
5:11:01 PM web.1 |  'vendor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
5:11:01 PM web.1 |  operable program or batch file.
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  null
5:11:01 PM web.1 Exited with exit code 1
```

Comment: you need .end file at your local set up. Copy the configs from heruko to .env

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this [dyno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku#Architecture) in your Procfile:

```
local: php -S localhost:8080
```

And use this dyno to run Heroku on local.

Start the Heroku local server by this command:

```
heroku local local
```

Then open <http://localhost:8080/>.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good idea, because it's loading the local PHP server, which is totally different to how Heroku will be running the app. Having said that, I'm not sure myself how to set up the Procfile for both dev and prod use!

Comment: Heroku also run the php server on its own terminal by giving the command in procfile.